# ruby on rails Why is the layout not being changed while loading css in view?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby on rails  Why is the layout not being changed while loading css in view?
The current code is as follows

[I will attach a screen shot of the display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk2O5.png)

confirm_csv.html.erb

```rb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "confirm_csv", :media => "all" %>
・・・etc
```

config/initializers/assets.rb

```rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( confirm_csv.css )
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```css
/*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

app/assets/stylesheets/confirm_csv.css

```css
table {
align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Rails 5, rename application.css to application.scss and confirm_csv.css to confirm_csv.css.scss. Also add this line in the application.scss `@import "confirm_csv.css"`.